# Convert String to Date java error

Tags: java

My date in string format is **2016-09-17 12:12:44**.
I am converting it to date object by this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date endDate = sdf1.parse(expiry);
```

The output is Sat Sep 17 00:12:44 GMT+05:30 2016. However the output should be:
Sat Sep 17 12:12:44 GMT+05:30 2016

Comment: If the parsing of the hour part is incorrect, perhaps you should examine the hour part of the formatting pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) **H** - represents 24 hours format and **h** - represents 12 hours format with am/pm

So the format should be **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date endDate = sdf1.parse("2016-09-17 12:12:44");
        System.out.println(endDate.toString());
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are not useful. Say *what* you changed, and more importantly, *why*.

Answer (score 1):

`h` is "Hour in am/pm (1-12)". Without an am/pm indicator, the assumption is a.m. Use `HH` where you have `hh`:

```
String expiry = "2016-09-17 12:12:44";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
// ------------------------------------------------------^^
Date endDate = sdf1.parse(expiry);
System.out.println(endDate);
```

Output:

```
Sat Sep 17 12:12:44 GMT 2016
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/13ctU9)

...or update your string to include an am/pm indicator and add `a` to the format string.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-09-17 12:12:44".replace( " " , "T" ) )
```

## Details

The [Answer by Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39543931/642706) is correct.

## java.time

Even easier is use with the modern [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

These classes use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default in parsing and generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern for such strings.

Your input string can be made to comply by replacing SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2016-09-17 12:12:44".replace( " " , "T" );
```

We parse as a `LocalDateTime` since your input lacks any info about offset-from-UTC nor time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

By context, you know this value is meant to be a time in India. So apply a time zone of `Asia/Kolkata` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```